# Occasional Segfault when rearranging doubly linked list

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I'm sorry if this may seem trivial to some but for the past day, I cannot for the life of me figure out why this segfault occurs. I have an array of doubly linked lists that I maintain a certain order in. Everytime a node in a list is accessed or updated, it is moved to the head of the list and this happens in each linked list within the array. I will provide the code of how I initialize the array of linked lists and how I arrange the order. Any help appreciated. If it helps, the array of doubly linked lists is in order to simulate a cache. Im just hoping its something glaringly obvious as I am a bit new to malloc and C. First time using this site so please let me know if I am not following convention or doing something wrong with my post

I've tried printing out the structure of the linked list array and it seems to always be structurally sound. The segfault only occurs when im rearranging the nodes, specifically when I try to access Node->prev->next. Not only this, it is happening when i am updating a tail node specifically

````
void maintainLRU(cacheBlock* ptr, int index)//rearranges a list with node passed in to be head
{
    if(ptr->next == NULL)//Tail
    {
        ptr->next = cache[index].head;
        cache[index].head = ptr;
        cache[index].tail = ptr->prev;
        ptr->prev->next = NULL;
        ptr->prev = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = cache[index].head;
        cache[index].head = ptr;
        ptr->prev->next = NULL;
        ptr->prev = NULL;
    }
}

//following code exists within main and is how i initialize the'cache'
numLines = cacheSize/(blockSize*assocType); //determines number of linked lists in my array. 
cache = malloc(sizeof(cacheLine)*numLines);
for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
{
        cacheBlock* temp = malloc(sizeof(cacheBlock));
        temp->valid = 0; //whether the node holds data yet or not
        cache[i].head = temp;
        for(int j = 1; j < assocType; j++)//assoctype is just how many nodes in the list
        {
            temp->next = malloc(sizeof(cacheBlock));
            temp->next->prev = temp;
            temp->next->valid = 0;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cache[i].tail = temp;
}//cacheblock is just a node with next, prev, and a valid bit
//cacheLine is just a struct with a pointer to a headnode
//the maintain order function is explicitly called only if the node updated or accessed is not the head.```
````

Comment: can you provide more details，for example,complete code.

Comment: @Whozcry I am a bit reluctant to because it is a homework assignment. so i tried providing code to what I believe is relevant but i might have not provided enough. Would it be okay for me to do so here?

Comment: Maybe `prev` is `NULL`

Comment: @kairos maybe you can, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Whozcry Even though its solved, thanks for your time. I really do appreciate the fact there are people willing to help others like this

Comment: @kairos It's ok. Hope someday that you also can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case 1: ptr is at end of list
 you remove yourself properly, put yourself at the head of the list, but do not make the “old” head of the lists prev point to you; so your list is corrupt.

case 2: ptr is not at end of list
 you point your prev at your next, but don’t point your next at your prev so your list is corrupt.

all cases: you should provide enough of a program that someone can compile it and try it.   In part, this will cause you to analyze your work enough to notice obvious errors.  The subtle ones are what this forum is for.

3 decades ago, it was really important to tightly optimise linked list operations; in that time the compiler nerds have upped their game enough that you should be able to write maintainLRU as:

```
void maintainLRU(cacheBlock* ptr, int index) {
    list_remove(&cache[index], ptr);
    list_insert_before(&cache[index], cache[index].head, ptr);
}
```

so you don’t fall victim to simple mistakes.

Comment: It was exactly as you said. I feel ridiculously silly and ashamed as it probably seemed like I didnt spend enough time. Something so obvious as pointer management and I spent a day+ on this one segfault. Thank you. Im unsure how to reply to your answer so I posted this as a comment. I guess I just need more experience with doubly linked lists in particular. Thanks again man.

Comment: i was also reluctant to post more code than necessary as it was a homework assignment and I was unsure on how to handle that and whether posting full code is even encouraged.

Comment: Sorry to drag you back here  again but I had a quick question. Are those list functions prewritten functions from another header file? If so I had no idea one for linked lists and you have added something very valuable to my toolkit so thank you. How do you know when or where to look for something like this?

Comment: No, just a generic set of list operation; if you look in /usr/include/sys/queue.h you will see something like them.   You shouldn’t feel ridiculous, I have probably spent months debugging list operations over my career.   rite of passage in some ways.